# How to connect from Azure function app to my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, virtual-machine, azure-functions

So when some event goes to event hub it triggers Azure **Function App**, which should now connect to my SQL Server on virtual machine Windows Server 2012 and do some command there.

My VM is online and has password, my SQL Server instance has no password.

How do I create right connection string for connecting to this instance and be able to execute commands?

**Note 1**

All resources are on the same Azure Subscription

**Note 2**

I have IP address of virtual machine, I made login user so I have username and password to login on SQL Server instance, I tried using this format of connection string(https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/):

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Still can't connect

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2012 R2** version - only **2012** - corrected

Comment: what do you  mean by `my SQL Server instance has no password`

Comment: are your instances in a virtual network and you are using windows auth ?

Comment: **Windows Server** sorry. I made login with username=Admin, password=***** , but and I got IP address of Virtual Machine but can't connect to server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You must allow the connection through the firewall on the VM
2. You must allow the traffic in the Network Security Group applied to your VM's network card
3. You must use SQL authentication

Another option is that you use VNET integration in the Function App, though I am unaware how it works in Functions. Then you could use the private IP address, and by default only the VM firewall could block you.

Your connection string looks correct, the only thing that it is missing is the SQL Server instance name, but it will work if you are using the default name.

Comment: 1. Firewall is turned off in VM
3. I am using it

2. I don't know what this is

Comment: Then number 2 is your problem :) Open your VM settings in Azure Portal, go to Network Interfaces, click the card there, then find Network Security Group, and there you need to go to Inbound Security Rules and add an exception for the port(s) used by SQL Server.